# How does the output layer of this network which has 10 nodes correspond to an integer?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

```
ffnn = Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

```
ffnn_history = ffnn.fit(X_train,
                        y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_split=0.2,
                        callbacks=[checkpointer, early_stopping],
                        verbose=1,
                        shuffle=True)
```

```
ffnn_accuracy = ffnn.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)[1]
```

These codes are from https://github.com/stefan-jansen/machine-learning-for-trading/blob/main/18_convolutional_neural_nets/02_digit_classification_with_lenet5.ipynb.

I understand this network and how softmax function works. My question is, the output layer has 10 nodes. The output should be a vector of length 10 (the sum of the vector is 1). How does it matches the label y where y is an integer in the training and evaluating process (shouldn't it transform the output vector to the corresponding integer first)?

Does tensorflow automatically interpret the length-10 output vector to the corresponding integer or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the labels are one-hot encoded by the loss function [`sparse_categorical_crossentropy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/sparse_categorical_crossentropy):

```py
>>> y_true = [1, 2]
>>> y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
>>> tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
array([0.05129344, 2.3025851 ], dtype=float32)
```

---

The output `softmax(x)` can be interpreted as a probability distribution (`Σ softmax(x) = 1.0`). So e.g. `argmax(softmax(x)) = id_maxprob` is going to return you the index of the most probable class.

Hence, your target vector for your neural network is going to be 10-dimensional such that each integer `[0, 1, .., 8, 9]` corresponds to one node of the softmax-output.

With that being said, the target vector you're trying to predict is simply going to be one-hot encoded:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # == 0
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # == 1
..
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]  # == 9
```

In other words: If you have a batch of `images` and feed it to your network, the output will be `(n, num_classes)` (here `num_classes` is 10) and it is *you* who is going to do the final interpretation of the output e.g. by using `np.argmax` in order to get your final predictions.

```py
predictions = model(images)
predicted_ids = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

# Print each index == predicted integer
print(predicted_ids)
```

Also, note the following example:

```
>>> tf.one_hot([1, 2, 9], depth=10)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Do you mean the integer label of y will automatically be one-hot encoded by tensorflow? Because I didn't see it using argmax for output in training and evaluating.

Comment: @user900476 Well, this depends on where your data comes from. If your targets are actual integers 1, 5, 6, 2 etc. then you'll have to one hot-encode these labels beforehand. You can use `tf.one_hot()` in your case.

Comment: so do you mean I don't have to one-hot encode y in this case because it is from mnist dataset?

Comment: @user900476 In your particular case the encoding of the labels is taken care of by the loss function [`sparse_categorical_crossentropy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/sparse_categorical_crossentropy).

Comment: Thank you Stefan! I see it now. it uses the sparse_categorical_crossentropy function to match the vector to the integer.

Comment: @user900476 The documentation lacks a bit behind here it would seem. But glad I could help :)

Comment: @user900476 If this answer solved your question. Kindly accept it by clicking on that tick mark button.